# Forwarding the 3000 port to local webbrick server in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

Using nginx and phusion passenger to host site http://example.com and is running fine.However, I want to be able to forward http://example.com:3000 to the webrick server raise by running command rails s. How do i do that ?

Comment: Have you tried just that? It should work (although I have no idea why you would want to when you have a functioning production site). Remember that `rails s` will run as development, not production, by default.

Comment: Yes, it should just work, barring any firewalls you may have running on there.

Comment: Can't you just set the port as a parameter when starting passenger? passenger start --daemonize --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4000

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. The problem is that I am moving a very old rails app which only runs on old 1.8.7 ruby and rails version 1. The problem is that I cannot install ruby 1.8.7 on my mac so I am trying to set it up in production server but try out in development mode first.

Comment: Thanks guys disabling firewall worked. So i'd just need to add a rule to firewall to allow port 3000